# WPF application stays on top of all other windows on Windows Server desktop

Tags: wpf, windows-server-2012

We have a WPF application, where the main window **intermittently** stays on top of all other windows on the desktop. Even on top of dialogs that the application opens itself! And: we only see this when running on a Windows Server (we use mostly Windows Server 2012). Never on a Windows workstation (Windows 8 or 10).

For example, we can work with the application for hours, and suddenly there is no way to get other windows on top of our application. Not by selecting another window, not alt-tab, nothing. The only way to get out is to restart the application.

Code-wise, this is pretty much what we do:

```
MyMain main = new MyMain();
main.Initialize();
main.Show();
```

Where MyMain is defined like this:

```
public partial class MyMain : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Other properties on MyMain are the usual ones for a Window.

I have had experience of problems with GUI on Windows Server before. That was in the old MFC/Win32 days. (I think that was something with wrong dlls or dll versions.) Could some of that still give problems in WPF?

My apologies if this is an inadequate description, but I hope that someone may have experienced something similar and could advice.

Comment: Do you have any visibility or positioning changes in your code for the window?

Comment: If this is your main window, why don't you use StartupUri on your Application class ? It might resolve your issue

Comment: This typically is a result of the TopMost property on the window. But if your not setting it explicitly the default is TopMost=false.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Mafii: The only positioning thing we do is WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen".
KANAX: I will try, but could you explain why this might help?
Kelly: No TopMost settings here...